# Silverlight: Is there a way to indicate to the DataContractSerializer that a class is non-Serializable?

Tags: silverlight, datacontractserializer

Is there a way to indicate to the DataContractSerializer that a class is non-Serializable?

Comment: In what sense? Marked `Serializable`? From what I gather you use this type to serialize and deserialize your own types - if you know it isn't compatible, don't serialize. I know this is a generalization of sorts but more so a prompt for some context!

Comment: The problem is some developers are accidentally serializing classes that they aren't supposed to. So I need to find a way to either throw a runtime or exception or compiler error when they try.

Comment: So who is marking them with `DataContractAttribute`'s and `DataMemberAttribute`'s?

Comment: If you don't include any DataMemberAttribute's it will default to serializing all public properties.

Comment: Are the classes marked with the Serializable Attribute then? In which case you will have to use an opt out policy using the NonSerialized attribute

Comment: @Andrew:  This questions relates to Data Contract Serializing.  Silverlight doesn't support the `Serializable` attribute and the standard forms of serialization available in full .NET.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones yes was aware of that but what is puzzling is the OPs comment relating to leaving off the DataMemberAttributes results in serializing all public properties - DataContractSerializer is opt in?

Comment: @Andrew: `DataContractSerializer` does not require the types being serialized to "opt in".  `public class { public string Name {get; set; } }` is serializable by `DataContractSerializer` without any annotation or special constructor implementations or any additional interfaces being implemented.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - Crikey I was still in a pre .Net 3.5SP1 timewarp over the DCS ...these constraints/conditions were relaxed.. article http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2008/05/13/50934.aspx. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method that throws an exception saying "don't serialize me" and decorate it with the [OnSerializingAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).